# Add a picture to each Radio Button in Radio Button Group

Tags: sapui5

I want to implement a Radio Button Group where every Radio Button will have a picture next to it (on the left side of the radio button).

Is that possible? If so, how?

html:

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label metric-light-16-black pay-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="rdPaymentMethod">
        <label class="radio-group col-md-2">
            <span id="radio-group-1" style="margin-left: 0cm;"></span>
            <span class="radio" style="margin-left: 0cm;" />
            <img src="assets/images/card-mastercard.png" style="margin-left: 0cm;"/>

        </label>

        <label class="radio-group col-md-2">
            <span id="radio-group-2" style="margin-left: 0cm;"></span>
            <span class="radio"/>
            <img src="assets/images/card-viza.png"/>
        </label>

        <label class="radio-group col-md-2">
            <span id="radio-group-3" style="margin-left: 0cm;"></span>
            <span class="radio"/>
            <img src="assets/images/card-paypal.png"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript sap function:

```
var placeRadioButtonAt = function(radioButtonId, containingDivId, selected) {
    elements.push(radioButtonId);
    var oRB1 = new sap.ui.commons.RadioButton(radioButtonId, {
        selected : (selected==true),
        select : function() {}
    });

    oRB1.placeAt(containingDivId);
}
```

calling this function 3 time (for each radio button):

```
    placeRadioButtonAt("radio1","radio-group-1",true);
    placeRadioButtonAt("radio2","radio-group-2");
    placeRadioButtonAt("radio3","radio-group-3");
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47411457/5846045 That way, images can be displayed between  and text for each item without creating any custom control. However, displaying them horizontally is currently not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would extend the RadioButton control for allowing images to be added with each radio button, and also extend the RadioButtonGroup to allow adding the previous extended control as an aggregation.

**OBS**: *css classes rendering are missing, more details on renderer implementation can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f393916f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)*.

**Assumptions**:

1. The namespace was defined as `my.app` inside the `index.html` file
2. Inside your project folder (webapp or WebContents) you have created a folder for these custom controls, named `controls`

## RadioButton extension

```
sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/m/Image', 'sap/m/RadioButton'

], function (jQuery, Image, RadioButton) {
    "use strict";

    var CustomRadioButton = RadioButton.extend("my.app.controls.RadioButtonImage", {
        metadata: {
            "properties": {
                "imageSrc": "string"
            },
        },
        renderer: function (oRm, oControl) {
            var oImg = new Image({ src: oControl.getProperty("imageSrc") })
            oRm.renderControl(oImg);
            sap.m.RadioButtonRenderer.render(oRm,oControl);
        }
    });

    return CustomRadioButton;
}, true);
```

## RadioButtonGroup extension

```
sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/m/RadioButtonGroup'

], function (jQuery, RadioButtonGroup) {
    "use strict";

    var CustomRadioButtonGroup = RadioButtonGroup.extend("my.app.controls.RadioButtonGroup", {
        metadata: {
            aggregations: {
                buttons : {type : "my.app.controls.RadioButtonImage", multiple : true, singularName : "button", bindable : "bindable"}
            },
            defaultAggregation : "buttons",
        }
    });

    return CustomRadioButtonGroup;
}, true);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I looked at your first solution but I am not sure it answers my needs.
Let me explain. The current html I attached above is not suitable for radio button group. Instead it has **3 single radio buttons**. I want to combine them all into **one radio button group** (radio group). so I would probably need to create a method named: *placeRadioGroupAt(<someDivID>)*. how can I create this method and which div should I give it?
reminde you that I want all those 3 radio buttons inside this one element (radio group) to have a picture next to them.

Comment: @Matoy: I have updated my answer based on your comment. I totally passed the detail it should be a radio button group. This should work for you.

Comment: @Cassio: I followed your steps to create the custom Control. But the code is getting into a continuous loop and causing : Stack Overflow !!( :P). Error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. I think this is because of the code line: `oRm.renderControl(oControl);` which is causing the renderer method of itself again and again. We need to call the RadioButtonRenderer rather than the renderer method of itself.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj: Correct! Thanks for pointing it out. I just corrected the answer.

Comment: 0
down vote
This doesn't work.. I get an error "found in negative cache: 'CompleteSurvey/controls/RadioButtonGroupRenderer.js' from ./controls/RadioButtonGroupRenderer.js: 404 - Not Found" .

Here's how I implemented it in the view ;

xmlns:ri="CompleteSurvey.controls"

 <ri:RadioButtonGroup buttons="{path: 'view>answers', templateShareable: true}" selectedIndex="-1">                                         
    <ri:RadioButtonImage text="{view>AnswerLabel}" imageSrc="{view>SmileyUrl}" />                                       
</ri:RadioButtonGroup>

Comment: @AdamHarkus: Can you try running in incognito mode once and confirm if you get the same error? Also, i think there is problem with binding. Guessing `answers array` is present from root, binding should be: `<ri:RadioButtonGroup buttons="{path: 'view>/answers', templateShareable: true}"`