# How to Add Descriptive Texts for Radio Buttons?

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement: I need to add descriptive texts for Radio Buttons as shown below.

[image: mock up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to add such a description under the text of [sap.m.RadioButton](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.RadioButton). However (same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47411457/5846045)), you can achieve similar behavior, look, and feel in the following combination:

- Use [sap.m.List](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.List) with

  ```
  mode="SingleSelectLeft"
  backgroundDesign="Transparent"
  showSeparators="None"
  ```
- In its `items` aggregation, use a subclass of [ListItemBase](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListItemBase) that supports `description` / `info`. Use [CustomListItem](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.CustomListItem) if nothing suites.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/List",
  "sap/m/StandardListItem", // or ObjectListItem, CustomListItem, etc..
], (List, StandardListItem) => new List({
  mode: "SingleSelectLeft", // displays radio buttons.
  showSeparators: "None", // between items
  backgroundDesign: "Transparent",
  includeItemInSelection: true,
  width: "19rem",
}).addItem(new StandardListItem({
  title: "Others",
  description: "3rd Party Vendor Lis",
})).placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="true"
></script><body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact" id="content"></body>
```

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann would it be possible to combine 2 different modes in a List, say I want SingleSelectLeft as well as Delete at the same time

Comment: @Ren Unfortunately no. You'll have to either switch to the `Delete` mode or use `CustomListItem` with `SingleSelectLeft` and a dedicated button for deletion.